# Deep-linking not fired from WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, deep-linking

I'm trying to fire the deep-linking in my Android application from the application `WebView` but instead of firing the ACTION_VIEW intent i get `ERR_UNKNORN_URL_SCHEME`, the website tries to make a `window.location.href = app://ls.mydomain.it/?key=XXX`.

The WebView is load in a Fragment like this:

```
    binding.webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    binding.webview.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    binding.webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?,request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
    binding.webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    binding.webview.loadUrl("https://ls.mydomain.it/?deviceId=${deviceId}")
```

I have added the deep-linking in the Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.components.home.HomeActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="app" android:host="ls.mydomain.it" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And then override the intent in the Activity:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
        val data: Uri? = intent.data
        newLicense(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that your internal webview can automatically handle deeplink to match the definition in your manifest. Imo, the way to handle that case is to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method, then try to parse the uri and then navigate to wherever you want .

Comment: Remember to return true in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` if you handle the url, or false to tell your webview to handle it.

Comment: @fshdn19 I've solved the issue by sending a `ACTION_VIEW` intent from the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by calling the `startActivity` with `ACTION_VIEW` intent which contains the deep-link `URI` by overriding the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

The WebViewClient looks like this now:

```
    binding.webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?,request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            val url = request?.url.toString()
            if (url.startsWith("app://")) {
                try {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).apply {
                        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER or
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_DEFAULT
                        }
                    }
                    startActivity(intent)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    showToast("Non è stato possibile attivare la licenza, contattare l'assistenza")
                }
                return true
            }

            return false
        }
    }
```

With `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_DEFAULT` flags the intent will match only the URI that matches the application deep-linking.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#avoid-a-disambiguation-dialog)